# Using url rewriting and visual studio link validations

Tags: asp.net

I'm doing URL rewriting using Routes (so nice, no need for external libraries)

But question is about VS2010. How do I stop it from giving me warnings like

```
File '/testimonials-customer-success-stories' was not found.
```

This is good link for URL rewriter but not a good link for my project.